# No JMX Connection Possible to Remote IP but on another Machine it works

Tags: linux, networking, jmx

Situation:
We have a VM with instanced Application runing with Java jre 1.6.37
All instances have an virtual IP and an own host name on that linux VM which i can see as eth0:1 eth0:2 etc.
there are also entries for all instances in hosts

Now for one of the Instances i added the JMX Monitoring Parameters to wrapper.conf:

```
wrapper.java.additional.7=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
wrapper.java.additional.8=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=6423
wrapper.java.additional.9=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
wrapper.java.additional.10=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

(we also tried it additional with adding: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=YOUR_IP YOUR_APP)

Problem:

I restarted the Application and tried to connect to that Application with JConsole from a Windows PC with JDK.
Connection was not possible.
When i telnet on the machine and Port 6423 i can connect.

Analyze Tries.

We also copied JDK to that linux machine and tried it there with same result.
So i tooked another VM where also the same Applications are running instanced with virtual IP etc.
There the connection was possible.

For the first VM there is no Firewall blocking the connection or something like that.
the `netstat -an |grep 6423` also tells me that it is LISTEN

I don't have any idea why it is working on the one VM but not on the other one also not with locally called jconsole to that virtual IP and Port 6423